# What are the key-value pairs on a form which finally get POST'ed?

Tags: http, post, curl

I have looked in stackoverflow and googled for this question but havent found anything relevant. Given a web-page with a form, which is possibly implemented through loads of javascript/.NET etc... I am trying to get the list of key-value pairs that I need to pass to it so that my program (lets say, using curl) can perform an HTTP POST. Any pointers/tips will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest thing to do is to install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in firefox and use the NET tab to observe what exactly is posted with your form.

Comment: Thanks folks. I will try using Firebug

Answer (score 1):

You can look for every input in the form : the key is the name of the input, and the value is its... value. :) Checkboxes send a value of 1 when checked, otherwise 0, `<select>`s send the value of the chosen option, etc.

A fastest way is to use Firebug. Send the data with Firebug on the Network tab and just look at your request in it.